SELECT statement has a cartesian product between FROM element(s)
For my bot to rate a user's appearance in Aiogram 3 I tried to implement saving user ratings and for this I created a second model:
class Profile(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'profile'

    id_all: Mapped[int] = mapped_column(primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)
    id: Mapped[str] = mapped_column(String(40))
    name: Mapped[str] = mapped_column(String(30), nullable=False)
    gender: Mapped[str] = mapped_column(String(8), nullable=False)
    age: Mapped[str] = mapped_column(String(30), nullable=False)
    country: Mapped[str] = mapped_column(String(30), nullable=False)
    city: Mapped[str] = mapped_column(String(30), nullable=False)
    photography: Mapped[str] = mapped_column(String(150))
    description: Mapped[str] = mapped_column(String(255), default='')
    count_grades: Mapped[int] = mapped_column(default=0)
    all_grades: Mapped[int] = mapped_column(default=0)


class NewGrades(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'newgrades'

    id_all: Mapped[int] = mapped_column(primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)
    id_user: Mapped[str] = mapped_column(ForeignKey('profile.id', ondelete='CASCADE'))
    liked_id: Mapped[str] = mapped_column(String(40), default=None)
    new_count_grades: Mapped[int] = mapped_column(default=0)
    grade: Mapped[int] = mapped_column(default=None)

    profile: Mapped['Profile'] = relationship(backref='newgrades')

Error:

sys:1: SAWarning: SELECT statement has a cartesian product between FROM element(s) "newgrades" and FROM element "profile".  Apply join condition(s) between each element to resolve.

To add information to a table and obtain information from it I use the following ORM:
async def orm_add_grade(session: AsyncSession, data: dict):
    obj = (NewGrades(
        id_user=data['id'],
        liked_id=data['liked_id'],
        grade=data['grade']
    ))
    session.add(obj)
    await session.commit()


async def orm_update_new_count_grade(session: AsyncSession, profile_id: int, new_count_grades: str):
    query = update(NewGrades).values(new_count_grades=new_count_grades).where(
        NewGrades.id_user == str(profile_id))
    await session.execute(query)
    await session.commit()


async def orm_get_grade(session: AsyncSession, profile_id: int):
    query = select(NewGrades, Profile).where(NewGrades.id_user == str(profile_id))
    result = await session.execute(query)
    return result.scalar()

Handlers in which I use this:
@user_assessment_router.message(or_f(F.text.contains('Rate'), F.text.contains('➡️Skip')))
async def grade(message: Message, session: AsyncSession, state: FSMContext):
    await state.clear()
    profile = await orm_get_random_profile(session, message.from_user.id)
    await state.update_data(liked_id=profile.id)
    await state.update_data(all_grades=profile.all_grades)
    await state.update_data(count_grades=profile.count_grades + 1)
    await state.update_data(id=message.from_user.id)
    await message.answer_photo(
        profile.photography,
        caption=f'''⭐️Name: <strong>{profile.name}, {profile.age}</strong> years\n
Country: <strong>{profile.country}</strong>
City: <strong>{profile.city}</strong>
{profile.description}''',
        reply_markup=get_keyboard(
            '1',
            '2',
            '3',
            '4',
            '5',
            '6',
            '7',
            '8',
            '9',
            '10',
            '➡️Skip',
            'Main menu',
            sizes=(5, 5, 2),
        ))
    await state.set_state(AddProfile.grade)


@user_assessment_router.message(AddProfile.grade, F.text)
async def next_grade(message: Message, session: AsyncSession, state: FSMContext):
    try:
        s = int(message.text)
        if 0 < s < 11:
            await state.update_data(grade=message.text)
            data = await state.get_data()
            grade_info = await orm_get_grade(session, message.from_user.id)
            await state.update_data(new_count_grades=grade_info.new_count_grades + 1)
            await orm_add_grade(session, data)
            data = await state.get_data()
            await orm_update_new_count_grade(session, data['id'], data['new_count_grades'])
            await orm_rate_profile(session, data['liked_id'], int(data['grade']) + int(data['all_grades']))
            await orm_count_grades(session, data['liked_id'], int(data['count_grades']))
            await grade(message, session, state)
        else:
            await message.answer('❌Ratings from <b>1</b> before <b>10</b>❌')
    except:
        await state.clear()

